# Python num = num +1 in loop

Tags: python

I don't understand why this error occurs:

```
num = 0

for i in range(2, 30):
    j = 2
    prime = "is"
    while j < i:
        if i % j == 0:
            prime = "not"
            j = j + 1

        else:
            j = j + 1

    if prime == "is":
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
    else: prime = "is"

SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
```

if num is defined before the if or the while statement, the script will just print a "1" for every prime number between 1 and 29 as opposed to counting how many primes there are.

Comment: I don't see any error if I fix the indentation of the outer for block. Its also ambiguous about how much of that code should be under the first `for` block. Is it all of it or just up until the end of the `while j < i:` block.

Comment: Make sure your formatting is correct, especially in Python. It's unclear whether you're asking about a logical error or the syntax error from your code snippet.

Comment: Which os also how are you running this? It it running in IDLE?

Comment: idle yes, and I fixed the formatting. In the shell it was correct I just miss-formatted the question

Comment: the error highlights the first line of the code as problematic not the last, the else statement is fine as is.

Comment: @SpencerHancock can you include the entire traceback error in the question?

Comment: Here's a couple things: You should switch over the statements from the format `x = x + 1` to `x += 1`; The last line is redundant and should be removed. Prime is set to "is" at the start of each loop, so you are just setting it twice; `==` should be replaced with `is`. `==` is for byte comparisons, `is` is what you want

Comment: Are you pasting this code into an interactive shell session as one giant block?  If so, I think that may be the problem.

Comment: Thanks all, I put it into jupyter notebook and for whatever reason it ran in there and then worked afterwards in idle. I still do not understand what changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think `j=2` (and the remaining code) should not be in the same level as `for`.

Comment: yeah, I missed that when I asked the question, the code after the for is indented

Comment: does it work after you fix the identation of for loop, and also `else` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The error is at last line you need to place else and print statement in two different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Where the code block in a "for loop" begins and ends is determined by indentation. 
Your "for loop" effectively does nothing because it has no code block.